# How can I upload custom profile picture of user in wordpress from front end other that gavatar without using plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom registration form in wordpress frontend with custom fields. Everything is working fine. Now I need to upload custom user profile picture from same form. How can I handle file upload and tag with user as profile picture?

Comment: do you use any plugin??

Comment: @Vasim Vanzara I don't want to use any external plugins.

Answer (score -1):

There is a good article explains how you can do that .
Here you will learn how to associate a user profile pic and also how to upload from front end.
 [Add Image Uploader](http://stevenslack.com/add-image-uploader-to-profile-admin-page-wordpress/)

Comment: Please read this before answering http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. You should write code over here and for reference you can give link.

Comment: i will do . thanks for letting know . just wanted to help

Comment: Broken link isn't usefull